# angular route with asp.net MVC remove hash # on url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, ngroute

I'm developing a web application using ASP.NET MVC and AngularJS with ngRoute module.  The configuration works fine but URLs contain `#/` and I would like to remove them. I know the point is adding `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and `<base href="/">` in the `<head>` but there is some conflict with server side routing and I can't get it work.

This is the route provider

```
$routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "Home/Phones",
        controller: "firstController"
    })
    .when("/phone", {
        templateUrl: "Home/Phone",
        controller: "secondController"
    })
```

Pages can be normally accessed through `http://localhost/test/#/` and `http://localhost/test/#/phone`.

Now if I add `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` and `<base href="test">` in the header section of index page I can access the default page at `http://localhost/test/` but the page is empty. Trying to access  and I get an error at `http://localhost/test/phone` fires 404 page not found.

So... how to solve the first problem? Console doesn't show any error, don't know what to try...

I guess I should at least change my `RouteConfig.cs`, not it contains the default

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The browser is requesting an asset `/test/phone` but that doesnt exist. In the case of 404s within a Single Page App using html5Mode you need to configure your webserver to serve the index.html on all "404"s